# How to distribute a survey form through WhatsApp?

Tags: forms, whatsapp, survey

How can I send this survey form link to many WhatsApp contacts (mainly small business owners and shop-keepers)

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to do this successfully by simply adding the URL of the survey into a WhatsApp message. This isn't the most efficient option for a large survey audience but it will solve the problem. Using the WhatsApp Web interface made this easier than doing it on a phone/tablet.

Also, these resources might be useful:

- https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/